# Casting Object[] to String[] error

Tags: java, object, casting

I need this code, but i get this error:

Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.lang.String

```
public Object[] getAllKeys (){

    return keys.toArray(new Object[keys.size()]); 
}

public String[] getNames (){

    return ((String[])super.getAllKeys()); <- Error here. Can't cast, why?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

toArray() returns an array of Objects. If you want to create an array of Strings out of it, you will have to do it yourself. For example,

```
Object [] objects = super.getAllKeys();
int size = objects.size();
String [] strings = new String[size];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  strings[i] = objects[i].toString();
```

or something similar... Hope this is useful.

Answer (score 6):

The type of the array is `Object[]` so it cannot know that it contains only `String`s. It is quite possible to add a non-`String` object to that array. As a result the cast is not allowed.

You can return `Object[]` and then cast each of the objects within that array to string. i.e. `(String)arr[0]` or you can create a new `String[]` array and copy all the elements over before returning it.

Answer (score 1):

Every String is an Object. Every Object is NOT a String.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do the cast, because even though `Object` is a base class of `String`, their array classes `Object[]` and `String[]` classes are unrelated.

You can fix this problem by introducing an additional method that allows taking a typed array:

```
public Object[] getAllKeys (){
    return getAllKeys(new Object[keys.size()]); 
}
// Depending on your design, you may want to make this method protected
public <T> T[] getAllKeys(T[] array){
    return keys.toArray(array); 
}
...
public String[] getNames (){
    return super.getAllKeys(new String[keys.size()]);
}
```

This code takes advantage of the other [overload of `toArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29), which accepts a typed array as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done implicitly since the runtime cannot know that the elements in `Object[]` are all `String` types.

If you don't want to code a loop yourself, then one way to coerce is to use

`String[] myStringArray = Arrays.asList(keys).toArray(new String[keys.length]);`

I *think* that this will happen without any string copies being taken: `asList()` binds to the existing array data and `toArray` uses generics which are removed at runtime anyway due to *type erasure*. So this will be faster than using `toString()` etc. Don't forget to deal with any exceptions though.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet

`Object[] obj = {"Red","Green","Yellow"};
 String[] strArray = (String[]) obj; // Casting from Object[] to String[]`